# In Unity object from ObjectPool appears with wrong direction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my game i have ship that shoots lasers, i made shooting using ObectPool, but got stuck with lasers wrong direction. I make them move by adding RelativeForce, but they move sideways forward. I tryed to instantiate objects with _placeToSpawn.transform instead of its position, but instantiated object are childs of Ship and when ship moves lasers move too. How to set force direction of activated laser right?

[Video of wrong moving lasers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Miakl9up80c&feature=youtu.be)

ObjectPool code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Linq;

public class ObjectPool : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField] private GameObject _placeToSpawn;
[SerializeField] private int _amount;

private List<GameObject> _pool = new();

protected void Initialize(GameObject prefab)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < _amount; i++)
    {
        GameObject spawned = Instantiate(prefab, _placeToSpawn.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        spawned.SetActive(false);

        _pool.Add(spawned);
    }
}

protected bool TryGetObject(out GameObject result)
{
    result = _pool.FirstOrDefault(gameObject => gameObject.activeSelf == false);

    return result != null;
}
}
```

Ship shooting objects from ObjectPool code:

```
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(AudioSource))]
public class ShipShooter : ObjectPool
{
[SerializeField] private UIdata _score;
[SerializeField] private GameObject _laser;
[SerializeField] private AudioClip _shootAudio;
[SerializeField] private AudioSource _indestructibleSource;
[SerializeField] private float _laserSpeed;
[SerializeField] private float _laserShootVolume;

private AudioSource _source;
private bool _laserShooted = false;

private void Start()
{
    Initialize(_laser);
    _source = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
}

private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        CreateLaser();
    }
}

private void CreateLaser()
{
    if (TryGetObject(out GameObject laser))
    {
        SetLaser(laser);
    }

}

private void SetLaser(GameObject laser)
{
    laser.SetActive(true);

    laser.transform.SetPositionAndRotation(transform.position, transform.rotation);
    laser.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddRelativeForce(Vector2.up * _laserSpeed);
    laser.GetComponent<Laser>().score = _score;
    laser.GetComponent<Laser>().source = _indestructibleSource;
    _source.PlayOneShot(_shootAudio, _laserShootVolume);
    _laserShooted = false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked with this line code instead of 44 line:

```
laser.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(transform.up * _laserSpeed);
```